# Why when I try create table in SQLite by python it shows me: error near "<": syntax error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I test  commands for sql by python. Generaly everything is okey, in this case, its doesn't work.

```
import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect('Chinook_Sqlite.sqlite')


cursor = conn.cursor()

result = None

try:
    cursor.executescript("""CREATE TABLE <New>;""")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
except sqlite3.DatabaseError as err:
    print("Error: ", err)
else:
    conn.commit()


print(result)


conn.close()
```

Comment: i am not sure, if even SQLLite allows to create table with the name <New> and without any columns

Comment: your table name is  <New>?

Comment: yes, it is "New"

Comment: Then why are you writing `<New>`?

Comment: I tried 'cursor.executescript("""CREATE TABLE New""")', now error is 'incomplete input'

Comment: Have you tried looking up what a table-creation statement has to look like? https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Name writes with out <> and must include: name, type, default value after in ().
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html - thanks @deceze

> The "CREATE TABLE" command is used to create a new table in an SQLite
> database. A CREATE TABLE command specifies the following attributes of
> the new table:
>
> - he name of the new table.
> - The database in which the new table is created. Tables may be created    in the main database, the temp database, or in any attached
>   database.
> - The name of each column in the table.
> - The declared type of each column in the table.
> - A default value or expression for each column in the table.
> - A default collation sequence to use with each column.
> - Optionally, a PRIMARY KEY for the table. Both single column and    composite (multiple column) primary keys are supported.
> - A set of SQL constraints for each table. SQLite supports UNIQUE, NOT    NULL, CHECK and FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> - Optionally, a generated column constraint.
> - Whether the table is a WITHOUT ROWID table.

```
cursor.executescript("""CREATE TABLE New ( AuthorId             INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, AuthorFirstName      NVARCHAR (20)    NOT NULL, AuthorLastName       NVARCHAR (20)    NOT NULL, AuthorAge            INT               NOT NULL);""")
```